# Why do only the linear transformations that send an edge to an edge preserve the n-gon?

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

I am asked to compute all the linear transformations $A:V\to V$ that preserve the general $n$-gon. We define the $n$-gon by using the roots of unity as vertices. I know that there are $2n$ such transformations, $n$ rotations and $n$ reflections, all of which send an edge to an edge.

A linear transformation is completely determined by its action on a basis; so, I take the vectors defined by two adjacent vertices, $v_1$ and $v_2$, as my basis, and define a linear transformation by choosing the points on the $n$-gon where I want to send them. Not every linear transformation that sends $v_1$ and $v_2$ to distinct vertices preserves the $n$-gon, though. Why do only the linear transformations that send $v_1$ and $v_2$ to adjacent vertices preserve the $n$-gon.

It might also be possible to approach this problem in another way because rotations are akin to multiplication in the complex field.

Comment: Is the question this? "If a linear transformation $A : V \to V$ (here $V$ is the Euclidean plane) bijectively maps the $n$th roots of unity to the $n$th roots of unity, then why does it map the line segment between two adjacent roots of unity to another such line segment?"

Comment: @Travis, Mostly, but it also maps all the points on the line segments between the $n$th roots of unity forming the $n$-gon so that image of the $n$-gon under $A$ is still the $n$-gon. Why are such transformations $A$ exactly those that map adjacent vertices to adjacent vertices.

Comment: If you already know that $A$ maps edges to edges, then it maps the endpoints of edges to the endpoints of edges, and in particular adjacent vertices to adjacent vertices. Is this not what you mean?

Comment: @Travis we assume that $A$ maps the entire $n$-gon to the entire $n$-gon. It does not seem trivial to me that it also maps edges to edges. I ask why it maps edges to edges; in particular, maps adjacent vertices to adjacent vertices.

Answer (score 1):

The edge $e$ from $v_1$ to $v_2$ can be parametrized as the set of points 
$(1-t)v_1 + tv_2$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.  Since the transformation $A$ is linear, the image of $e$ under $A$ will be $(1-t)A(v_1) + tA(v_2)$ which is 
the edge from $A(v_1)$ to $A(v_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Two (nonantipodal) vertices $v_1, v_2$ are adjacent iff there is no vertex $v'$ that can be written as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2$ with positive coefficients.

> So, if $A v_1, A v_2$ are not adjacent (NB they cannot be antipodal), there is some vertex $A v'$ that we can write as $$A v' = a_1 A v_1 + a_2 A v_2 = A(a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2)$$ for some positive $a_1, a_2$, and, since $A$ is invertible, $v' = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2$. Thus, $v_1, v_2$ are not adjacent.